# Microsoft Bot calling Bot or Orchestrating Multiple Bots

Tags: botframework, bots, cortana-skills-kit

I would like to know if there is way to connect multiple bot's (build using microsoft bot framework )together so that there will be one parent bot and other being children. The diagram I have attached is my desired state.

[Desired Bots Orchestration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmYEc.png)

Comment: Can you provide some more information and show specifically where you are stuck with this design? As this question stands it is too broad.

Comment: I do not have a design. I am asking if is it possible do something like this with the bot framework ? does framework support it ?
Is there anything out of the box that can be used.

Ex: there LUIS dispatcher to combine multiple LUIS and QnA app so routing becomes easy.

Answer (score 0):

So it's possible to do what you're asking, but the levels of support that you're hoping for from the BotBuilder SDK might not exist. I'm going to interpret your last statement in your comment as asking about routing utterances to multiple NLU models; there is a tool called [Dispatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/Dispatch) that can be used to connect multiple LUIS and QnA Maker Models together.

#### The Diagram:

To start off with, this Middleware layer you're using before deciding to route to a "Parent" bot or "Children" bot is unnecessary. You can just do this from the "Parent" bot to remove moving parts. Most bot designs I've seen do this, but if you have specific thoughts about the "Middleware" layer you could explain more. To reiterate, it sounds like it's just another routing layer that could instead be in your "Parent" bot.

The next item is that you don't need to necessarily create multiple bots for each task; instead you can create multiple dialogs inside your bot to handle Alarm Management, History Management and Feedback Management. If you're attempting to use multiple bots to route to these children bots then it makes more sense as to why you would want the children to be individual bots. However, unless you have 3 bots with alarms, I recommend putting the dialogs from each bot into your "Parent" bot.

Personally speaking, there should be a very strong case as to why each of these topics and child tasks need to be in separate bots, otherwise I would just put all of this into one bot.

[image: Picture of your design diagram]

Comment: I see what are you trying to explain.

Comment: I see what are you trying to explain but I think I need to stick to multiple bots scenario. Here is the reason why.
My company has over 20K associates and probably several 100 teams. There are few teams who are interested in building bots using botbuilder. My team owns and reserves right to have 1 production bot with multiple channels. We want each team to create their own bots but parent will be ours. 
ex: 
Master BOT - support scheduling , and routing to children
Child 1 - Hr bot
child 2 - Heath issues Bot 
child  3- immigration issue bot 

etc.

Comment: @RoyJ same scenario am trying, like Master Bot to Child Bots, have you implemented. What kind of architecture do you following?

Comment: @RoyJ same scenario am trying can i know is there any sample or any web links on this

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to have a Parent Bot to "talk" with child Bots?

You can do it using DirectLine channels where your recipient is your child bot (you have to set at ChannelAccount ID the bot handle).

Like you can create a client that can send a message to your bot using a direct line.

See this: [Direct Line Testing](https://azure.github.io/learnAnalytics-AdvancedFeaturesforMicrosoftBotFramework/lab02-testing_bots/docs/3_Direct_Line_Testing.html)